# How to iterate with two arrays inside an array using the filter() method

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions

How can i get it to enter .map() block?
Is it possible to do this or do i need to approach this issue in another way?

```
var orderCompetences = [];
var nActiveApplicants = [];
function MatchCompetences() {
 var _applicantCompetenceResults = nActiveApplicants.filter(xApplicant => {
   xApplicant.applicantCompetences.map(applComp =>
   orderCompetence.map(orderComp => {
     console.log(applComp ); //never gets called
     console.log(orderComp);//never gets called
     return applComp === orderComp;
  }));
});

 return Promise.all(_applicantCompetenceResults)
 .then(resp => {
   console.log(resp); // Never gets called
   return 1;
 })
 .catch(err => {
   console.log(err);
   return 0;
 });
}
```

An object inside `nActiveApplicants`

```
nApplicant = {
  applicantID: "",
  applicantPeriods: [],
  applicantCompetences: [],
  applicantFullAddress: "",
  applicantDuration: ""
};
```

Comment: First of all `Promise.all` accepts an array of Promises, second, `_applicantCompetenceResults ` should be a promise and then you can put it in `Promise.all`. Can you post some `nActiveApplicants` object sample ?

Comment: @darklightcode I added some more code.

Comment: You can't filter Objects. You mean `nApplicant` is an array of objects ? What about `orderCompetence` ? is this a separate array ?

Comment: `nActiveApplicants` is an array of `nApplicants`. `orderCompetence` is a seperate array. @darklightcode

Comment: Several problems here: 1. You're not returning anything from your `filter` function. 2. Where is `val` coming from?

Comment: `MatchCompetences` is never called. Your `filter` callback does not *return* anything. `_applicantCompetenceResults` is therefore empty. If it would not be empty, it would not contain promises. There is more than one thing wrong with that code.

Comment: `MatchCompetences` gets called from another method. So i only need to return `xApplicant.applicantCompetences.map(applComp =>
      orderCompetence.map(orderComp => {
        console.log(applComp);
        return applComp === orderComp;
      })
    );` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presumed that you want some of the `applicantCompetences` to exist in `orderCompetences`, using the `find` method to search for a valid result, and then filtered it. I mapped the remaining records into Promises.

```js
function MatchCompetences() {

  var nActiveApplicants = [{
      applicantID: "abcd",
      applicantPeriods: [],
      applicantCompetences: ['can read', 'can talk', 'useless mostly'],
      applicantFullAddress: "",
      applicantDuration: ""
    },
    {
      applicantID: "efgh",
      applicantPeriods: [],
      applicantCompetences: ['can read', 'can talk', 'singer mostly', 'it-will-do'],
      applicantFullAddress: "",
      applicantDuration: ""
    }
  ];

  var orderCompetence = ['it-will-do'];

  var _applicantCompetenceResults = nActiveApplicants.filter(xApplicant => {

    return typeof xApplicant.applicantCompetences.find(elem => {
      return orderCompetence.indexOf(elem) !== -1;
    }) !== 'undefined'

  }).map(item => {

    return new Promise(resolve => {
      resolve(item);
    })

  });

  return Promise.all(_applicantCompetenceResults)
    .then(resp => {
      console.log('remaining applicants', resp); // Never gets called
      return 1;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      return 0;
    });
}

MatchCompetences()
```

Comment: The issue is incorrect data format but thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you want something like this, although it's not clear to me why you'd wrap this in a `Promise.all`, since I'm pretty certain `_applicantCompetenceResults` won't be an array of Promises:

```
var orderCompetences = [];
var nActiveApplicants = [];
function MatchCompetences() {
  var _applicantCompetenceResults = nActiveApplicants.filter(xApplicant => 
    xApplicant.applicantCompetences.some(applComp => orderCompetences.includes(applComp))
  );

  return Promise.all(_applicantCompetenceResults)
    .then(resp => {
      console.log(resp);
      return 1;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      return 0;
    });
}
```

If this doesn't do the trick for you, you may want to try to explain what you're hoping to achieve, rather than get into the details of the code you're working with.

Comment: I am trying to get all applicants that have at least 1 matching competence.

Comment: The example code should do that for you if I understand the data correctly. I have corrected the code since I first posted my answer.

Comment: @NathanBerhe I updated this again - I had an errant semi colon that was causing it to fail. I've tested it, and it should solve the actual problem correctly now.

Comment: The issue is incorrect data format but thanks for pointing me in the right direction.